# Is there a free character builder for D&D 4e on Mac?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, tool-recommendation

Is there a free character builder available for Dungeons and Dragons 4e on a Mac? Preferably, a user friendly one. I would like it to be a stat generator along with class and race selection, and allowing me to pick my skills. I would also like it to be able to be printed out, but that's not a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[D&D4.com](http://dnd4.com/dd-4th-edition-character-sheet) has an Excel spreadsheet character sheet with pretty much everything you're looking for. While the sheet won't randomly roll your Ability scores, it will show you how many points you have remaining for point-buy. Similarly, the sheet will tell you how many more skills you have to train. The sheet will highlight fields you need to fill in when you level up (eg, your new level grants a feat, the next feat slot will be highlighted yellow until you fill it in). Most fields with a finite number of options also have a dropdown menu to select from, filtered based on class/race/ability scores/level/etc. requirements.

It's not perfect, but in my opinion it's the next best thing to Wizards' character creator when it comes to 4e characters.

I don't have experience with trying to use spreadsheets on a Mac, but since the sheet does not use any Macros (VB scripts), only calculations and data validation, I suspect it would work fine in something such as OpenOffice.